# Why is inline-block list item showing on two lines? Text includes a number (which shouldn't matter?)

Tags: css

What on earth could be causing that 5 to move down on a second line? Other list items have more characters and I even added a number to 'Foo Fighters' just to see if it was caused by an int character, which displayed as it should.

[image: snapshot of inline list, the text Maroon 5 is split on two lines.]

```
<ul id="soundsLike">
    <li>Foo Fighters</li>
    <li>Maroon 5</li>
    <li>Paramore</li>
    <li>Jimmy Eat World</li>
    <li>none of these</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#soundsLike {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#soundsLike li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:3px 5px;
    background:#57A957;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    font-size:80%;
    line-height:14px;
}
```

Comment: can you show us it in action? probably a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, please provide more CSS at the minimum.  I do not have the problem you mentioned with the supplied code.

Comment: Sorry, it's an enormous CSS file. The problem is coming from this style on the body `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`

Comment: Is there a wrapping element with a fixed width on it? That may be creating the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code on it's own doesn't have that problem (see: http://jsbin.com/avufay/1/) so there must be something else affecting it.

One thing that should prevent this though is putting `white-space: nowrap;` to the '#soundsLike li' styles.

Comment: Yes, even with `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` applied the `white-space:nowrap;` fixed it. Thanks!